# Condição IF em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando adicionar uma condição IF em meu exercicio de estudo em jQuery e estou com um pequeno problema.

o código abaixo cria uma pequena lista de tarefas e quando clicado em cima do div criado pelo jquery o mesmo é apagado.`

```js
var main = function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
    var item = $('input[name=txtTarefa]').val();
    $('.lista').append('<div class="item">' + item + '</div>');
    })
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    $(this).remove();
      })
  }
$(document).ready(main)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="painel">
  <label for="acao">Tarefa:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtTarefa" class="tarefa" />
  <button name="btn" id="button">Adicionar</button>
</div>

<br />

<div class="lista">
  
</div>
```

O problema é que se eu tento criar uma condição antes de apagar o item a condição não é executada.
por exemplo;

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
var apagar = confirm("Deseja apagar a tarefa?");
if (apagar){
$(this).remove(); }
  })
```

Comment: Não entendi bem qual é o problema e como reproduzi-lo.

Comment: Eu tentei adicionar um IF para perguntar ao usuário se ele deseja apagar uma DIV e esse IF não funciona.

Comment: Testei aqui e funcionou normalmente, veja se é isso que quer: http://jsfiddle.net/mzrhefh0/

Comment: Almeida, funcionou sim.
no codepen.io não esta funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

Repara que estás a usar a versão `1.2.3` do jQuery. Essa versão é muito antiga e ainda não tem [o método `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) introduzido na versõ `1.7`. Muda para uma versão mais atual e já vai funcionar.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="painel">
    <label for="acao">Tarefa:</label>
    <input type="text" name="txtTarefa" class="tarefa" />
    <button name="btn" id="button">Adicionar</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="lista"></div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j49m5khg/